# Facebook look alike status update textbox

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I need to create a facebook look a like status update textbox.
I mean, first it will be like a tiny slim textbox and when user clikcs on it,
it will become big, kind of textarea.

does anybody has any idea about how to do it??

N.B. Please see the attached image.[image]

Comment: Have you tried changing the height of the element when it's focused?

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?  what is not working.   We do not write code for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't necessarily need jQuery or JavaScript for this today. You can actually do this with pure CSS by using the [`:focus pseudo-class`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/cc304080%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) in your selector:

```
textarea {
  width: 500px;
  height: 20px;
}

textarea:focus {
  height: 100px;
  /* Uncomment for gradual resizing
  -webkit-transition: all 1s;
  -moz-transition:    all 1s;
  -ms-transition:     all 1s;
  -o-transition:      all 1s;
  transition:         all 1s;
  */
}
```

Dabblet: http://dabblet.com/gist/3429275?result

Answer (score -1):

Make two divs one with small text box and the other with textarea and the buttons at the bottom( with CSS ). Use blur() function of first textbox to hide itself and show the other div with textarea and the buttons. When the Post button is pressed the second div sould be hide and the first one should be shown.

Comment: Not sure of the practicality of this approach, personally.  Especially as we move more towards a "semantic Web", I would think that there are plenty of other options that are more semantically appropriate, whether through CSS pseudo-classes or scripting.